# how to automatically sync extjs calendar with outlook calendar without using .ics

Tags: extjs, calendar, synchronization, icalendar

I have ExtJS Calendar as a centralized calendar, users will access this calendar.
I want this to be automatically synchronize with users outlook calendar. as of now i am using ICS attachment but, i need a solution which will not force me to download attachment. **It should automatically update user outlook calendar.
Please help on this.**

Comment: You have to do the synchronisation on the server side.

Comment: Darin, can you plz explain how it is to be done, how to update user's outlook